# Drupal 7 views - Contextual filter content: Nid content id from url

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I am working on a portfolio website where there are a lot of projects on the website.

When you have a project node open I want a view next to it with all the thumbnails of other projects.

The problem is the following:
When I have the view setting set to Contextual filter content: Nid content id from url I want the reverse effect to happen. Because now it only shows the same node.

Please forgive my bad english, I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Let assume that you are using "Content: Nid" exposed filter.

Edit settings of your exposed filter and expand "More" section. If you choose "Exclude" check-box then it will show all nodes except current one.

Please see screenshot - how it used to be.

[image]

Comment: So used to the "more" area only having a field to rename the entry I didn't even look in it...Thanks, very straightforward and helpful answer.