# Override a node page of specific content with views page

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I want to create a views for overriding the node page for specific content. For example, when I click the link of a node in a list page, by default , it will go to the node page (e.g node/1), but I want to display a views page, so I can customize the views by views rather than customize the display in content type.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check my answer at [Redirecting Pages from Standard Node page to views page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/175696/redirecting-pages-from-standard-node-page-to-views-page/175721#175721)

Answer (score 0):

Create a views of content, set path of it to something like **mynode/%**(or what you want(yourpath/%)), add contextual filter **Nid**, set default value **Get Content ID from Url**,and then customize views fields with what you want.
 [This link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/48465/drupal-7-views-contextual-filter-content-nid-content-id-from-url) can help you about how to pass Nid to views

Comment: does it force redirect /node/1 to /mynode/1 ?

Comment: you can when you data render link every node to 'mynode/nid` or you can redirect `/node/nid` to `/mynode/nid`(with rules or in hook_init)